# Emplace a derived movable but noncopyable in a vector gives compilation error

Tags: c++, vector, emplace, noncopyable

I'm having compiler errors when trying to `emplace_back` in a vector of non-copyable but movable objects with a subtle inheritance twist, that should to my knowledge not change the problem.

Is this legal C++ and this a Visual Studio 2015 bug, or am I making an obvious mistake ?

```
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}

    Base(Base&) = delete;
    Base& operator= (Base&) = delete;
};

class Test : public Base
{
public:
    Test(int i) : m_i(i) {}

    Test(Test&&) = default;
    Test& operator= (Test&&) = default;

protected:
    int m_i;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Test> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(1);
}
```

Output :

```
error C2280: 'Test::Test(Test &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Without the inheritance, that is with deleted copy constructor in Test and no base class, it compiles correctly.
Somehow, removing the default in the move-constructor make it compile correctly also, but then I have to define the move constructor and I don't want to go there.

Which means this compiles fine :

```
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int i) : m_i(i) {}

    Test(Test&) = delete;
    Test& operator= (Test&) = delete;

    Test(Test&&) = default;
    Test& operator= (Test&&) = default;

protected:
    int m_i;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Test> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(1);
}
```

Puzzling ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is correct in all the cases you described.

When `Test` is derived from `Base`, its defaulted move constructor is defined as deleted because it tries to move `Base`, which cannot be move-constructed. `Test` is actually not move-constructible in your first example.

In your second example, with no base class, there's nothing to prevent the defaulted move constructor from being defined, so `Test` becomes move-constructible.

When you provide a definition for the move constructor, it's up to you to handle `Base`. If you just write

```
Test(Test&&) { }
```

this will just default-construct a `Base` object, so the move constructor will compile, but it probably won't do what you want.

---

`Base` is not move-constructible because it has a user-declared copy constructor, which prevents the implicit declaration of a move constructor - it has no move constructor at all - and its copy constructor is deleted (it couldn't handle rvalues anyway because it takes a non-const reference).

If you make `Base` move-constructible, by adding, for example,

```
Base(Base&&) = default;
```

then `Test` also becomes move-constructible, and your example will compile.

---

One last piece of the puzzle: since we have declared a move constructor for `Test`, why does the error message reference the deleted copy constructor, even in the first case?

For an explanation of `std::vector`'s logic for choosing which constructor to use to copy / move elements during reallocation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34167803/4326278). Looking at the logic that [std::move_if_noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept) uses to choose which kind of reference to return, it will be an rvalue reference in our case (when `T` is not copy-constructible, the condition is always false). So, we'd still expect the compiler to attempt to call the move constructor.

However, one more rule comes into play: a defaulted move constructor that is defined as deleted does not participate in overload resolution.

This is done so that construction from an rvalue can fall back to a copy constructor taking a `const` lvalue reference, if available. Note that the rule does not apply when the move constructor is explicitly declared as deleted.

Comment: Oh yes, the public Base in the second example was a typing mistake, I'll edit it